# Cannot find module './mergeConfig' when running on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a node application that runs fine when executed on my machine via `node my_application.js`.

However, if push it to heroku and execute it via `heroku run node my_application.js` or with the scheduler what I get is this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './mergeConfig'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I'm running node v10.16.0 and npm v6.9.0 both locally and on Heroku, so I really don't know what may be causing this issue, and googling for it didn't help in any way.

Any ideas about this `mergeConfig` module that seems to be missing from my heroku environment but not from my local environment?

Edit: this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "[REDACTED]",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[REDACTED]",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "form-data": "^2.3.3",
    "http-to-curl": "^1.4.2",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "qs": "^6.6.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "simple-oauth2": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json`.

Comment: Does `mergeConfig` appear in your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`? Is it a module you wrote yourself, or something that comes from a private package repository? Are you depending on it directly (and if so why isn't it in your `package.json`) or is it an indirect dependency? I can't find it on NPM (though there is [`merge-config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-config)).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add explicitly the missing module in the dependencies in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
       ...
       "merge-config" :"2.0.0"
       ...
}
```

I think it works on your local environment because you have the module installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
'./mergeConfig' is a file inside de axios module.

Path: node_modules/axios/core/mergeConfig.js

For some reason heroku had a problem with this file.
I solved it by replacing axios with request.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by `I solved it by replacing axios with request.`

Comment: I reaplaced in my code the package "axios" [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for the package "request" [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: I don't really want to rewrite all my application to use another HTTP request library instead of axios, though :(

Comment: I find a better solution, downgrade de axios package to version 0.18.1

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

src: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1767#issuecomment-416924946